# Use TYPO3-cache to store values

Tags: php, caching, typo3, extbase

Is there a way to use the typo3 cache for data generated in one of my extbase extensions? I have a script to generate the navigation, which is rather complicated but which shouldn't change too much, so after getting a result I would really like to use the typo3 to store it (and when someone hits the "flush all caches" button it should be flushed too).

Is that possible? If so - how?

Comment: Yes, you can use the caching framework. Here is the documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/CachingFramework/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 provides a Caching Framework for such tasks.

The documentation can be found at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/CachingFramework/Index.html

Here is a small example which can be used as a wrapper around your Generation:

```
public function generateMenu(array $pageUids)
{
    $cache = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\CacheManager')
        ->getCache('fashionesta_newsletter');
    $cacheIdentifier = md5(implode($pageUids));

    $menu = $cache->get($cacheIdentifier);
    if($menu !== false) {
        return $menu;
    }

    // Generation logic

    $cache->set($cacheIdentifier, $menu, array(), 60 * 5);
    return $menu;
}
```